# Calculate limit for continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I am having trouble with this question:

if f(x) is a continous function and $$ 1 - x^2 \leq f(x) \leq e^x $$ for all values of x, calculate $$ \lim_{x\to0} f(x) $$.

Do I have to calculate the limit on both sides of $f(x)$? How would I got about solving this?

Comment: What happens to the bounding functions as x goes to zero?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, the $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0)$, FWIW. Unless $f$ is only defined on $(0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 7):

A function $f$ with the given property cannot exist. For $x=-\frac12$ we would have
$$ 0.75 = 1-(-1/2)^2 \le f(x) \le e^{-1/2} \approx 0.61 $$
but $0.75 \not\le 0.61$.

Comment: I second this answer! But the question holds when the range for the values of $x$ is restricted though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take limit on all three sides:
$$1=\lim_{x\to0}(1-x^2)\le\lim_{x\to0}f(x)\le\lim_{x\to0}e^x=1$$

Comment: Continuity of $f$ is not needed in the assumption.